# Where to copy executable file for mpi?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm using MPI for performing parallel processing, after i compile the application using mpicc, where do i copy the executable file on other machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The MPI implementation will invoke it for you on the remote machines when you call the `mpirun` (or equivalent) command to launch your application.